# How to change the standard blue hover and frame effect?

Tags: css, vaadin, theming

I am using Vaadin version 14.6.3.

[Hover and selection effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsTpK.png)

In the image above you can see that my app has a greenish color scheme, but the context menu I implemented will always have a blue hover effect and also some blue frame for the active item.

I tried to play around with stlyes.css and shared-styles.js, but I could not manage to find the correct place where to add/overwrite the standard blue "lumo" behavior.

What can I do to customize this behavior to a color of my choice?

```
@Route(Pages.CUSTOMER_ROUTE)
@StyleSheet("styles.css")
@PageTitle(Pages.CUSTOMER_PAGE_TITLE)
@JsModule("./shared-styles.js")
public class CustomerUI extends VerticalLayout implements RouterLayout, PageConfigurator, RoleSecured, AfterNavigationObserver {...}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have very likely only set the primary color and not also the 50% and 10% shade colors.  See https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/lumo/design-tokens/color/#primary

E.g. try:

```css
html, :host {
    --lumo-primary-color: hsl(122, 96%, 47%);
    --lumo-primary-color-50pct: hsl(122, 96%, 47%, 0.5);
    --lumo-primary-color-10pct: hsl(122, 96%, 47%, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: this was tested against 23.2, but it shows the same effect.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It bugs me to ask this stupid question, but where do I have to put it? I added a bit of code to show you how I set up the CustomerUI Route. As you can see I use shared-styles.js and styles.css. Should the lines you posted go to shared-styles.js or styles.css? I tried to find that information on the link you provided, but without success.
Also I was wondering if I can access this from the Java-side, because I would like to make this coloring configurable by the user.

Comment: @DanielKlemm Follow the instructions to create a [Custom
Theme](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/custom-theme/creating-custom-theme);
so you would add those lines in the beginning of
`frontend/themes/your-theme-name-here/styles.css`.  If you prefer to
keep your current approach, the answer is "the same place where you have
put your primary color override" and then hope for the best.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. It actually solved my issue!
I had to disable the cache in my browser so that the changes actually became visible. This took me another hour...

In the end it works!

Still one question remains: Is there any way to configure this in the java code / so that a customer could set up their own color scheme e.g. per app user?

Comment: Yup, you can do this in e.g. your root layout class:

UI.getCurrent().getElement().getStyle().set("--lumo-primary-color", "red");

Note, however, that those --lumo-primary-color etc properties are used for all the parts that are blue by default, so changing them changes all of those blues.

Comment: Or if you just want to provide a bunch of color variant themes to choose from, you can implement those in a stylesheet, prefixed with a classname or theme name like so:

[theme~="red-theme"] {
  --lumo-primary-color: red;
  // etc
}

and then apply that theme attribute dynamically in a similar manner:
UI.getCurrent().getElement().setAttribute("theme", "red-theme");